# Facebook post sharing popup

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, share

I would like to share somethin from my iOS application to user's Facebook wall.
I'm able to present the official login webview but I was wondering how to present this kind of view after the user has been logged successfully ...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create a Facebook instance let call it _facebook. You call following method

```
NSMutableDictionary paramters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"<app id>", @"app_id", @"http://...", @"picture", nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:parameters andDelegate:self];
```

parameters can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/